# Unmarshalling LocalDate/LocalDateTime with MOXy

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, moxy

How can I get MOXy to unmarshal JSON into `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime`?

I've got an `@GET` method which produces a sample instance with three fields of types `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` and `Date`, respectively.

Hitting that endpoint, I get:

```
{
    "localDate": "2017-07-11",
    "localDateTime": "2017-07-11T10:11:10.817",
    "date": "2017-07-11T10:11:10.817+02:00"
}
```

I then POST the above data to my `@POST` method, which simply returns the data again:

```
{
    "date": "2017-07-11T10:11:10.817+02:00"
}
```

As you can see, both `localDate` and `localDateTime` are lost in the process, because MOXy does not initialize those two fields.

What gives? MOXy seems to support serialization of these types, but not deserialization?

```java
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

@Path("/test/date")
public class DateTest {
    public static class Data {
        public LocalDate localDate;
        public LocalDateTime localDateTime;
        public Date date;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("roundtrip")
    public Response roundtrip() {
        Data sample = getSample();
        return roundtrip(sample);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("roundtrip")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response roundtrip(Data t) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(t).build();
    }

    protected Data getSample() {
        final Data data = new Data();
        data.localDate = LocalDate.now();
        data.localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        data.date = new Date();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Moxy version: `jersey-media-moxy-2.25.1`

Comment: Is it really "serializing" (in the more common sense) or is it simply calling toString()?. There's a difference. Until MOXy/JAXB actually supports Java8 time, you'll probably need to [use an XMLAdapter](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html). Or you can use Jackson instead of MOXy, and [use its Java8 time support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28803634/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet I didn't think of this possibility. I read [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26825079/383124) and understood that to mean that it was supported.

Comment: In that post I actually gave both examples of what I mentioned as solutions in my previous comment (i.e. use an adapter or switch to Jackson)

Comment: Actually, I think I need to update the post. I probably tested only using the serialization :-D

Comment: @peeskillet the XMLAdapter really solves this problem. In addition you may then specify the format how the LocalDateTime will be marshalled/unmarshalled. +1

Answer (score 2):

According to peeskillet's suggestion I implemented the following adapter class:

```
public class LocalDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime>{

  private static final DateTimeFormatter DTF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

  @Override
  public String marshal(LocalDateTime localDateTime) throws Exception {
    return localDateTime.format(DTF);
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(string, DTF);
  }

}
```

In addition, I created `package-info.java` in the same package where my classes for MOXy and the adapter (in a subpackage) are located with the following content:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDateTime.class,
      value=LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
})
package api;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;

import api.adapter.LocalDateTimeAdapter;
```

Thus, marshalling and unmarshalling works without problems. And with `DTF` you can specify the format that shall be applied.