# Jax-RS JsonFormat Date Unknown 39

Tags: java, rest, maven, date, jax-rs

**FilmEvent.java**

```
    import java.util.Date;

    @AllArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
    public class FilmEvent {
    @Getter
    private String id;

    @Getter
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm", timezone="CET")
    private Date date;

    @Getter
    private String[] attributes;

    @Getter
    private boolean soldOut;

}
```

My record

```
FilmEvent event = new FilmEvent("334",  new Date(2018,1,1,12,44), null, false);
```

My result in firefox

```
date:"3918-02-01,12:44"
```

Question is, Why 3918-02-01? and how to fix it;

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how you can edit your question to be more informative and clear, in order to enable other users to answer it. For further details, please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: You are using a long deprecated `Date` constructor. Best if you can avoid using `Date` at all. [The modern Java date and time API known as `java.time` (or JSR 310)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Whenever I need an old-fashioned `Date` object with a specific value, I use like `Date.from(ZonedDateTime.of(2018, 1, 1, 12, 44, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).toInstant())`. It’s longer, but it’s clearer to read, hard to get wrong and it specifies more precisely what I want and get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-int-int-int-int-int-) this `Date` constructor takes year argument as `year-1900`, thus your initial year is getting added by `1900`.

**JavaDoc:**

```
year - the year minus 1900.
month - the month between 0-11.
date - the day of the month between 1-31.
hrs - the hours between 0-23.
min - the minutes between 0-59.
```

This is also a deprecated long time ago. I would suggest using `LocalDateTime` from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

Comment: Seems to be good however it result in
date:{ 
year:2018
month:"JANUARY"
monthValue:1
dayOfMonth:1
hour:12
minute:44
second:0
nano:0
dayOfWeek:"MONDAY"
dayOfYear:1
chronology:{…}}
And i need just year,month,day,hour,minutes any tip please?

Comment: @Sumek which method have you chosen. Probably you need `LocalDateTime.of`. I bet you can find out which one is suitable for you from the source code here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html

Comment: I think about output not about methods. I have already done this, thanks for help.
Link to the output problem for the future.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804941/how-can-i-have-jax-rs-return-a-java-8-localdatetime-property-as-a-javascript-sty

Answer (score 0):

> Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min) **Deprecated**.  As
>   of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date,
>   hrs, min) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min).

you can use then:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 12);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 44);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

or

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2018,1,1,12,44);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```